# Why is there no current flowing across the battery

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, batteries

[image]

Okay so I solved this question which asked me to calculate the value of R such that 
there is no current flowing in the galvanometer branch.

(THE ANSWER IS 100 ohm)

I used the loop rule to write the equations and solve for R.

It was after I solved the question that the trouble started. Upon closer inspection I saw that the potential drop across the 100 ohm resistor was also 2 V (Like the battery on the adjacent branch). So why is no current flowing across the 2 V battery. It can be said that the battery and the 100 ohm resistor are in parallel (Equal potential drops). How is the battery different from the 100 ohm resistor ?

Answer (score 1):

It might be useful to think of some limiting cases to get some intuition.  For example, assume that R starts off being infinite (open circuit), then all the current would flow through the 2V battery, which would be (12-2)/500 = 0.02A.  Now, as you decrease the resistance, some of the current will flow through R as well, but only what is needed to satisfy V=IR, where V=2V.  When R is very large, I will be very small.  Once you get to R=100 ohms, then 100*0.02=2V, so that the 0.02 A when flowing through the resistor R will exactly produce the 2V drop and thus require no current through the 2V battery.  If R goes below 100 ohms, then you will again see current flowing through the 2V battery, but in the other direction.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Why is the 2V potential difference in the opposite direction of the battery's emf enough to stop current flow. I read that the potential of 2 points must be equal to stop current flow. How can we say that the potential difference between the positive terminal  and the node (after the 500 ohm resistance) are at equal potential?

Comment: The current meter/galvanometer (G) has zero voltage drop across it.  It is an ideal device.  I hope that helps.

Comment: The galvanometer branch has a potential drop of 0 since the 12 V battery imposes a 2 V drop across it and the 2 V battery does the same but in the opposite direction. Is that what you mean to say?

Comment: Actually, the galvanometer will always have a potential drop of zero under all conditions because it is ideal - meaning zero resistance.  This is the definition of a perfect galvanometer.  In the case of your problem, the node after the 500 ohm will always be at 2V potential because the 2V battery is attached there through the "ideal" galvanometer.  The currents will then be whatever is needed to satisfy Ohm's law, as earlier explained.  I hope this helps.

Comment: When you say the node will be at 2V what is your reference point in the circuit?

Comment: The negative terminals of both batteries, or the bottom of your diagram - same thing.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101426/discussion-between-aditya-ahuja-and-ad2004).

Answer (score 1):

Think of a water pipe system.

- The **resistor** is like a **filter**. It allows some water through (from any direction) but slows it down.
- The **battery** is like a **pump**. It literally forces water from one side to the other, and allows no water to flow the opposite way.

A battery is a fairly complex electrochemical device, but it does indeed act as a one-way charge mover, which via high chemical potentials separate electrons from atoms at one terminal and reunites them at the other. This causes a constant surplus of negative charge at one terminal and a lack at the other, and this charge difference corresponds to an electrical potential energy difference, measured as **voltage**. Think of **voltage** as water **pressure difference**.

Those surplus electrons want to move, and the only available path they have is through the circuit (and thus they constitute a current - think of **current** as the **water flow**) because they aren't able to move through the liquid interior of the battery. This liquid (or maybe in the future non-liquid) **electrolyte**, as it is called, is an ion conductor, but not an electron conductor.

Sure, rechargeable batteries (accumulators) are not "one-way streets", so the analogy is not perfect and depends a lot on the exact conditions. But the one-way pump idea works fairly well in most cases.

Comment: “but it does indeed act as a one-way charge mover” you might want to say this applies to non rechargeable batteries

Answer (score 0):

The 12v battery is supplying current to R through the 500 ohm resistor that is equal to the current R would draw from the 2v battery, so they equal out.

Comment: Check my comment on ad2004's answer.

Comment: "they equal out" and therefore get cancelled out by superposition?

Comment: If you removed the 2v battery the circuit would work the same.

Comment: If I remove the 2V battery wouldn't the 100 ohm resistor be shorted out?

Comment: When you say that the currents equal out, how does that imply that the current in the galvanometer branch is 0 ?

Comment: It may help if you think of the resistors as 2 different sized light bulbs, one with 500 ohms resistance, one with 100 ohms resistance, remove the 2v battery, they shine the same

Comment: @Aditya Ahuja When Adrian says remove the 2 volt battery it means replace it with an open circuit not a short circuit. Then, given R=100, the voltage across R it will still be 2 V. Do you not understand that?

Comment: @Bob D I know that the potential drop across R will remain same. How does that ensure that the current in the 2V branch is 0?

Comment: @Aditya Ahuja If you know removing the battery doesn’t affect the circuit why would you expect putting it back in will cause current to flow in the potentiometer?

Comment: @Bob D I think I finally got it.When we set  R=100 , the loop equations work out in such a that the current flowing through the primary circuit is exactly the current required to create a voltage of 2V across R (Which will always be the case since it is connected in parallel to the 2 V source). Just clear one thing for me. For there to be  a voltage drop across a cell, does there have to be a current ?

Comment: @AdityaAhuja For the first part, I think you got it. For the last question, if by cell you mean the battery then the answer is obviously there does not have to be a current. If you connect nothing to the cell there is still a voltage across it.

Comment: @AdityaAhuja The cell generates the voltage by means of chemical reactions within the cell.